Send audio stream from microphone in SwitUI iOS App to Firebase Cloud Functions
After doing some research, I found how send an audio file to Firebase Storage and then read that file in Firebase Cloud Function to do some processing. However, I am got stuck on trying to figure out how to stream audio file directly to Firebase Cloud Functions. Does anyone have any ideas?
Here is what I have tried so far:
- Sending entire audio file (code below)
- Looking at HTTP callable function documentation but I did not find any examples for stream
Thanks so much for your help!
func startRecording() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)

        let documentPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let audioFilename = documentPath.appendingPathComponent("myVoice.flac")
        let settings: [String: Any] = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatFLAC,
            AVSampleRateKey: 16000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 192000
        ]

        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder?.record()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to setup audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func stopRecording() {
    guard let audioRecorder = audioRecorder else {
        print("Audio recorder is nil")
        return
    }
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audioFileURL = audioRecorder.url
    self.audioRecorder = nil
    
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let storageRef = storage.reference()
    let audioRef = storageRef.child("\(audioFileURL.lastPathComponent)")

    audioRef.putFile(from: audioFileURL, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
        guard let _ = metadata else {
            print("Error uploading audio: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: audioFileURL)
        } catch {
            print("Error deleting local file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        
    }
}


This is not going to be easy, if it is possible at all.  Cloud functions are designed around discrete HTTP post operations. You are going to need to figure out how to POST http chunked data, probably via MIME/multipart and decode that in the cloud function.
